# Conteúdo de um JSON em uma célula da tabela

Tags: javascript, json, table, getjson

Como faço para pegar o resultado de um json e jogar direto dentro de um td da minha table? Está certa a forma do getJSON?

```
 <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('../js/gcs.json', function(data) {
                $('#inprog').append(data.inprog);
                $('#queued').append(data.queued);
                $('#total').append(data.total);
                $('#resolved').append(data.resolved);
        });
    });
</script>
```

O meu json é este:

```
            {
            "inprog" : "123",
            "queued" : "00",
            "total" : "103",
            "resolved" : "101",
            "20days" : "0",
            "8to20days" : "16",
            "5to7days" : "17",
            "1to4days" : "70",
            "csatess" : "80%",
            "csatcps" : "80%",
            "csatgcs" : "100%",
            "escalations" : "10"
            }
```

O meu HTML:

```
<table class="hovertable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <thead>
            <th colspan="6">DASHBOARD</th>
        </thead>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><b>INPROG > 50</b></td>
            <td id="inprog"></td>
            <td><b>> 20 days</b></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td><b>CSAT ESS</b></td>
            <td>80%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>QUEUED = 00</b></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td><b>8 to 20 days</b></td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td><b>CSAT CPS</b></td>
            <td>80%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>TOTAL < 50</b></td>
            <td>103</td>
            <td><b>5 to 7 days</b></td>
            <td>17</td>
            <td><b>CSAT GCS</b></td>
            <td>100%</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><b>RESOLVED >70</b></td>
           <td>101</td>
           <td><b>1 to 4 days</b></td>
           <td>70</td>
           <td><b>ESCALATIONS</b></td>
           <td>10</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>       
</table>
```

UPDATE:

Meu código todo está assim, mas ainda não tive sucesso.

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('../js/gcs.json', function(data)  {
            var table = document.querySelector(".table tbody tr")
            //pegando a tabela  

            //inserindo dinamicamente o objeto dentro da tabela  
            for(t in data){
                //t posicao do objeto retorna 'inprog'
                //objeto[t] retornaria '123'
                $(table).append("<td>"+ t + "</td><td>" +data[t] + "<td>")
            }         
        });
    });
</script>

<table class="hovertable table" border="1">
    <tr>
        <thead>
            <th colspan="6">DASHBOARD</th>
        </thead>
    </tr>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table> 
</html>
```

Alguém tem alguma luz?

Comment: Não funciona? Como é o teu HTML? já verificaste que `data` tem conteúdo?

Comment: Não funciona. Na verdade não sei como chamar estes valores do json para dentro do td. eu tentei com algo desse tipo: <td id="inprog"></td>

Answer (score 1):

Seu arquivo JSON está errado, pois não deve ter uma vírgula no final do último item.

Versão corrigida:

```
 {
    "inprog": "123",
    "queued": "00",
    "total": "103",
    "resolved": "101",
    "20days": "0",
    "8to20days": "16",
    "5to7days": "17",
    "1to4days": "70",
    "csatess": "80%",
    "csatcps": "80%",
    "csatgcs": "100%",
    "escalations": "10"
 }
```

Comment: Opa! Não tinha visto!

Comment: Caso tenha resolvido o problema, não esquece de aceitar a resposta ok?

Answer (score 1):

Verifique o console do seu navegador quando abre a página. Se você encontrar um erro similar a "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http..." é porque você está tentando rodar esse seu script sem estar em um servidor. [Nesse link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local) você encontra várias explicações de porque não se pode ler um arquivo local sem usar um protocolo como http.

Eu consegui executar o seu código e funcionou perfeitamente. Usei o servidor que vem embutido no php. Bastou rodar o comando
`php -S localhost:8080` no diretório do projeto, acessar essa url pelo navegador e digitar o caminho até o arquivo. Você também pode usar qualquer outro servidor http de sua escolha que irá funcionar.

Edit:
Caso você não possa usar um servidor para resolver o seu problema, terá que habilitar o seu navegador para permitir requisições XMLHttpRequest em arquivos locais. Eu sei que pro Chrome tem um plugin pra isso. Uma boa referência é [esse tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24903016/getting-a-json-file-using-jquery-without-a-web-server).

Answer (score 0):

Quando a solicitação dos dados for realizada nesse ponto abaixo

`$.getJSON('../js/gcs.json', function(data) {`

a melhor forma é varrer esse objeto chamado de data e ir inserindo dinâmicamente com o [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) do jquery

```js
//exemplo do objeto que retornou

data = {
  "inprog": "123",
  "queued": "00",
  "total": "105",
  "resolved": "101",
  "20days": "0",
  "8to20days": "16",
  "5to7days": "17",
  "1to4days": "70",
  "csatess": "80%",
  "csatcps": "80%",
  "csatgcs": "100%",
  "escalations": "10"
};
var table = document.querySelector(".table tbody tr")
   //pegando a tabela    
  
  //inserindo dinamicamente o objeto dentro da tabela 
for(t in data){
  //t posicao do objeto retorna 'inprog'
  //objeto[t] retornaria '123'
            $('#inprog').text(data.inprog);
                $('#queued').text(data.queued);
                $('#total').text(data.total);
                $('#resolved').text(data.resolved);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="hovertable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <thead>
            <th colspan="6">DASHBOARD</th>
        </thead>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><b>INPROG > 50</b></td>
            <td id="inprog"></td>
            <td><b>> 20 days</b></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td><b>CSAT ESS</b></td>
            <td>80%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>QUEUED = 00</b></td>
            <td id="queued">0</td>
            <td><b>8 to 20 days</b></td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td><b>CSAT CPS</b></td>
            <td>80%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>TOTAL < 50</b></td>
            <td id="total">103</td>
            <td><b>5 to 7 days</b></td>
            <td>17</td>
            <td><b>CSAT GCS</b></td>
            <td>100%</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><b>RESOLVED >70</b></td>
           <td id="resolved"></td>
           <td><b>1 to 4 days</b></td>
           <td>70</td>
           <td><b>ESCALATIONS</b></td>
           <td>10</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>       
</table>
```

Comment: E como eu faria para "desenhar" esta tabela? Aqui não estou conseguindo jogar o resultado do json na tela.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aí  @AlissonCunha  , atualizei aqui. Vê se esse exemplo funciona

Comment: Desenhou a tabela, mas não trouxe o resultado do json. :(

Answer (score 0):

Existe alguma outra forma de se copiar o valor de um elemento do json e jogar dentro de uma célula específica da minha tabela?